# Jquery-dataTables Error while drawing tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

The problem is with jquery datatables. I am getting the data from the url through ajax

calls. Since I am using codeigniter framework I am using datatables library to generate the

datatable objects using echo $this->datatables->generate() in this function advertisement-details-data

The output of the function is also right.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#example').dataTable
          ({  
            'bProcessing'    : true,
            'bServerSide'    : true,
            'sAjaxSource'    : '<?php echo base_url();?>advertisement-details-data',
            'iDisplayStart'  : 0,
            'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
            {
             console.log(aoData);
             $.ajax 
              ({
                'dataType': 'json',
                'type'    : 'POST',
                'url'    : sSource,
                'data'  : aoData,
                'success' : fnCallback,
                'cache'   : false
              });
            }
          });
});
```

and console.log was giving me an output which contains datatables outputs ... and in web

console also i cant find any js errors. Please help me to solve this issue

This is the output of the console.log in the datatables plugin http://pastebin.com/YS7NQAdp

This is the output of the advertisement-details-data http://pastebin.com/NiVvcp8A

Comment: What is the error specifically?

Comment: I am not able to view the tables ... Its like its not drawing tables 'Loading data from server' ....

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems wrong with your js code as you are getting proper response , but i would suggest get your json return from the server (using Firebug or whatever) and check in  http://jsonlint.com  to see what's wrong with it. for more you can check [datatables server side error](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/700/server-side-processing-hangs-at-loading-data-from-server/p1).

Comment: I have implemented datatables lot of times but this time i am not able to figure out the issue .. the json format is correct